# Does iText honors color transparency?

Tags: itext

I'm using iText 5.2.1 and I tried to use the BaseColor constructor with alpha channel, that is

```
public BaseColor(final int red, final int green, final int blue, final int alpha)
```

but when I actually draw text or shapes it seems that the alpha channel isn't taken into account.
For example if I try this

```
  Font f = ....;
  f.setColor(new BaseColor(130, 130, 130, 50);
  PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
  ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase("my text", f),
      refPointX, refPointY, 0);
```

the text it's written with the color specified but without the alpha information, that is with the color with 100% opacity.
The same thing happens if I try to draw some shape and I specify a fill color with transparency.

In the book *iText in Action second edition* there's nothing about transparency in colors.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Are you using Adobe Reader or another PDF viewer? Some non-Adobe PDF viewers handle transparent content differently than Adobe's, and the iText devs only use Adobe Reader as a reference.

Comment: I use Adobe Reader only. Have you some code that use color opacity?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I just wanted to discard a viewer issue. If you don't get an answer on SO, you might want to try to post your question to iText's [mailing-list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/itext-questions).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've found something in itext mailing list, I tried and... works!
It's a undocumented feature. Anyway the following code does what I need:

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
PdfGState gState = new PdfGState();
gState.setFillOpacity(0.1f);
cb.setGState(gState);
```

If a draw text or shapes, they have 10% opacity. With `gState.setStrokeOpacity` I can also set opacity on strokes.

Comment: If what you found totally solved your issue, consider accepting your own answer :)

Comment: If you are drawing a line, then the above works if you use gState.setStrokeOpacity(0.1f);

Comment: What does this code do? Make the whole document transparent? Only affect the following draw commands?

Comment: Yes it's making the whole document transparent. I was in need of text transparancy